# Redshift SQL - get top x% of values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to extrace data on the top 80% of a certain value. Say my dataset is

| Restaurant | Pizza | sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | P1 | 5 |
| R1 | P2 | 2 |
| R1 | P3 | 4 |
| R1 | P4 | 7 |
| R2 | P5 | 6 |
| R2 | P6 | 9 |
| R2 | P7 | 3 |
| R2 | P8 | 9 |

I have

```
select
restaurant
   ,pizza
   ,sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant order by sold desc rows unbounded preceding)::FLOAT / sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant) as running_total_sold_perc

from table
```

which gives me the share of pizzas sold per restaurant sorted descending. Now though about just adding

```
where running_total_sold_perc <= 0.8
```

However, I have the problem that some of my restaurant may sell only a small number of different pizzas, so maybe two pizzas together make up 70% of all sales (38%+32%) and one pizza makes up 30%. With <= 0.8 I would therefore only get two pizzas, covering 70% of sales, not 80%.
In my mind, instead of <=80% I need <="the smallest number that is larger than 0.8".

Can any one give me an idea how to implement this? Do I need to create another temp-table for the lowest number above 0.8 per restaurant or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the previous value of the running_total_sold_perc in your condition instead of the current running_total_sold_perc value. The previous value of the running_total_sold_perc can be calculated as the following:

`pre_running_total_sold_perc = (sold running sum - sold) / total sold sum.`

So, your query will be:

```
select restaurant, pizza, running_total_sold_perc    
from
(
 select restaurant
       ,pizza
       ,sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant order by sold desc)*1.0 /
        sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant) as running_total_sold_perc
       ,(sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant order by sold desc) - sold)*1.0 /
        sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant) as pre_running_total_sold_perc
 from table1
) T
where pre_running_total_sold_perc<0.8
```

Note that the condition should be `pre_running_total_sold_perc<0.8` not `pre_running_total_sold_perc<=0.8`, this will guarantee the selection of all rows that their running_total_sold_perc<0.8 including the first row with value >=0.8.

Comment: That's ineresting, I need to try it. If I understand this correct, you're constructing an offset. Wouldn't the calculation of `pre_running_total_sold_perc` need a rows-clause as this will give the total of `sold` without the respective row-value?

Comment: Actually, you may think of it as this, for numbers x<y<z, the running sum at z will be x+y+z and the pre running sum is x+y which equals to x+y+z-z. So, to get the previous running sum, simply subtract the current value.

Comment: I understand that. But the code gives an error because sum() over () needs a 'rows'-clause if it has an 'order by'-clause. So I changed it to ```sum(sold) over (partition by restaurant order by sold desc rows unbounded preceding) - sold```